# Find ascii Byte if Statement not working correctly

Tags: c#, byte, ascii

I am looking at a value on the text changed event of a text box so when we scan with a handheld it looks at it and if the ascii character 9 is at position 7 it should kick out what we want.  However this isn't working and not sure what I'm missing.  I have tried asciiBytes[0] == 0x80 and asciiBytes[0] == "9" neither worked..

```
protected void poTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(poTextBox.Text);

    if (asciiBytes[7] == 0x9)
    {
        string po = poTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 6);
        string item = poTextBox.Text.Substring(9, 15);

        poTextBox.Text = po;
        itemTextBox.Text = item;
    }        

}
```

Comment: Define "position". You didn't forget arrays are zero based did you?

Comment: Right.... we have a PO # that is P123123 so we want the 8th element is what we want which would be at 7 correct?

Answer (score 0):

C# arrays are 0-based. So the 7th position of an array would be `asciiBytes[6]`.

And if you want the character ASCII 9, which is the tab character, then compare to 9. If you want the character '9', then compare to `'9'`.

Also, the use of `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` is unnecessary and can cause problems here. Code should look something like this:

```
protected void poTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (poTextBox.Text[6] == 9)
    {
        // Etc...
    }        
}
```

Comment: Right.... we have a PO # that is P123123 so we want the 8th element is what we want which would be at 7 correct?

Comment: @ksuProgrammer: Well, I know this works. So you haven't described something right. Did you try the code above? Do you know how to use the debugger? If so, what is at `poTextBox.Text[7]`? Or maybe you don't really mean ASCII 9?

Comment: I will try code above yes I do know how to use the debugger... our problem is we have handheld scanners that won't read the ascii character and kick a new line.. but our Symbol scanners do.  So we are trying to beat the system persay it reads it as a string value like P2771489 then the item #... but it's a handheld scanner so hard to run debugger mode on it.  I will try your code quick we tried something similar to that earlier and didn't work.

Comment: Just tried it.. scanned in as P123456     145511.... so it reads the tab but won't kick a new line... we are just trying options.. tried to do a substring of (7,2) and if that was = to /t  then we would kick a new line but that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this by programming a tab key on the scanner so it fired the Text Changed event... then used this code:

```
if (poTextBox.Text.Substring(7, 1) == "\t")
    {
        string po = poTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 6);
        string item = poTextBox.Text.Substring(8);

        poTextBox.Text = po;
        itemTextBox.Text = item;
    }
```